# Difference between "Numix" and "Numix Daily" GNOME themes

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk, window

I have noticed that in the GNOME Tweak Tool there are options to change the themes of various things on your system:

[image]

And I have also noticed two Numix themes there:

- Numix
- Numix-Daily

Now I have an idea of what Numix is as I use the Numix-Circle theme for icons, however I do not know what the difference between the Numix theme, and the Numix-Daily theme is, so I was wondering if someone could explain as I do not see an obvious visual difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no difference. You have the PPA `ppa:numix/ppa` in your system and in this PPA is the package `numix-gtk-theme`. This package installs the Numix theme and creates a link as you can see in the output of the commands below

```
% cat /var/lib/dpkg/info/numix-gtk-theme.postinst 
#!/bin/bash

set -e

if [ "$1" = "configure" ]; then
    if [ ! -e "/usr/share/themes/Numix" ]; then
        ln -sf "/usr/share/themes/Numix Daily" "/usr/share/themes/Numix"
    fi
fi



exit 0
```

```
% ls -laog /usr/share/themes/                
total 48
drwxr-xr-x   8  4096 Sep 16 20:36 .
drwxr-xr-x 519 20480 Sep  8 18:00 ..
drwxr-xr-x   4  4096 Mär 25 07:31 Adwaita
drwxr-xr-x   4  4096 Mär 16  2015 Default
drwxr-xr-x   4  4096 Mär 16  2015 Emacs
drwxr-xr-x   4  4096 Mär 25 07:31 HighContrast
lrwxrwxrwx   1    29 Sep 16 20:36 Numix -> /usr/share/themes/Numix Daily
drwxr-xr-x   9  4096 Sep 16 20:36 Numix Daily
drwxr-xr-x   3  4096 Mär 16  2015 Raleigh
```

Answer (score 2):

Numix = stable release (current version)

Numix-Daily = unstable release (development version)

That is meant generally - in this special case, the answer of @A.B. is valid !

Comment: Mostly properly. But in this case not =)